# Create a stored procedure but getting this message

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

This procedure will update data in column but ended up with this message

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure updatetings , Line 26 [Batch Start Line 4]
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'BEGIN'.

This bold words is the problem come from

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE updatetings
    @i_id VARCHAR (50),
    @i_proccess VARCHAR (10),
    @i_line VARCHAR (50),
    @i_group VARCHAR (10),
    @i_date DATETIME

WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   SET  NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
   SET  ANSI_NULLS , ANSI_PADDING , ANSI_WARNINGS , ARITHABORT ,
   CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL , QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

    -- PROBLEM HERE 
    IF @i_proccess = 'xxx' 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE database SET
            date = @i_date,line = @i_line,Group = @i_group
        WHERE id = @i_id 
    END

END

EXEC updatetings '8','xx','xx','xx','2022-02-23 08:25:43.780'
```

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: It worked when I tried it... so dunno what your error is. Do you really have a table called database? Datebase and group are both reserved words, so if you are really using them you need to escape them.

Comment: Based on the syntax I think we can safely assume this is SQL Server and not MySQL.

Comment: What's the specific version of SQL Server you are using here, what's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION`? You have a number of language keywords there which should be surrounded by `[]` to avoid compiler errors, i.e.: `[database]`, `[date]` and `[Group]`.

Answer (score 0):

some answer is needed for when the IF does not have the result you expect

BEGIN
UPDATE database SET
date = @i_date,line = @i_line,Group = @i_group
WHERE id = @i_id
END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT 'Nothing to update'
END